# SPSS: How can I copy values from a variable (column) and paste it below the other one using syntax?

Tags: variables, syntax, spss

[SPSS] How can I copy values from a variable (column) and paste it below the other one by syntax?

I need to merge 10 columns and I cant do this only by copy paste.

I have this:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7NyP.jpg "tooltip"

```
      var1   var2
1       3       6 
2       4       7  
3       5       8
4        
5
.
.
.
```

and I want this:

```
     newvar
1      3
2      4
3      5 
4      6 
5      7
6      8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create new lines (so you get two lines with one variable instead of one line with two variables), You can use `varstocases` like this:

```
varstocases /make NewVar from Var1 Var2/index=originVar(NewVar).
```

this will get both the old variables into the new one, and create an additional variable called `originVar` which will contain the name of the original variable that each number in `NewVar` came from.

**ADDITION:**
if your file was originally sorted by a specific variable(s) you can now just sort again by your original variable and by `originVar`. If you don't have a variable that conserves the original order, just create one before rustructure:

```
compute OrigOrder=$casenum.
restructure....
sort cases by OrigOrder originVar./* or by originVar OrigOrder.
```

Your example may imply that you already have empty lined to which you want to copy values from previous lines. This is a different situation, you can do it this way:

```
compute NewVar=Var1.
if missing(NewVar) NewVar=lag(Var2).
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work because it changes the variables to cases and whole order changes.  What I am looking for is too keep the order as it is in the new varable. Look at my example please again !

Comment: you mean you don't want to create new lines but copy values to empty cells in existing lines?

Comment: compute NewVar=Var1.
if missing(NewVar) NewVar=lag(Var2).  I cant use this because all my culumns(variables ) are same long so it will only write the first variable values in the NewVar.

Comment: " you mean you don't want to create new lines but copy values to empty cells in existing lines? "               Yess thats exactly what I want with 10 variables that I have! I want to copy their values below each other in a new variable using syntax.

Comment: you lost me here... Please post a more full example (with row numbers) so we can better understand what the problem is and how to solve it...

Comment: thank you. I edited the question with row numbers.. Is there anyway that I can upload the screenshots here? maybe that would help.

Comment: there's an "add image" control above the editing panel. I guess I still don't really understand the problem well enough (I fail to see why the above solutions won't work for you).

Comment: what you suggested wont work because the order of the values after I use your commands change in the culumn. I could only upload one image. Its not allowed to upload two pictures here.

Comment: casestovar transposes my data. What I need is two copy the values of multiple culumns below each other in one culumn in plain english.

Comment: did you try `casestovars` and then sorting the file the way I suggested? you can get to the order you want in the file easily...

Comment: I tried to sort it via restructure window it didnt work. If you could please write me the whole code.

Comment: please send me your data (or a sample if it's a big file), I'll try to help with code: eli at hizun dot co dot il

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your kind gesture. I wish you the best.